How to type a dict argument in tool function of LangChain?
I'm using Gemini-1.5-flash model from langchain_google_genai.
When I try to bind this tool to the ChatGoogleGenerativeAI instance,
from langchain_core.tools import tool


@tool
def test(a: int, b: dict) -> str:
    """
    test
    """
    return f"a: {a}, b: {b}"

the error occurs like below
400 * GenerateContentRequest.tools[0].function_declarations[8].parameters.properties[b].properties: should be non-empty for OBJECT type

WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
E0000 00:00:1733636038.240366   20980 init.cc:229] grpc_wait_for_shutdown_with_timeout() timed out.

I searched around for hours and no article found about typing dict argument for langchain tool function.
How do I resolve this error and type the argument as a dict?

I tried...

removed b: dict from signature and the error didn't occur.
changed typing b: dict to b: dict[str, Any] and the same error occurred.

